# how to format ntfs use 4k as sector size?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

it seems that lastest hhd employ advanced format whose sector size is 4k. but how could I make ntfs use native 4k sector?

[image]

How to make the LogicalBytesPerSector to 4k?

Comment: All you need to do is ensure that your drive is properly aligned to a 4k boundary and that the cluster size is also a multiple of 4k. Most systems will do this by default when partitioning and formatting these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

That hard drive is already using 4K sector physically. These days all consumer hard drives are 512e (512 emulation), meaning they write in 4K sector on the platter but communicate to the motherboard in 512 bytes manner. This is necessary since no consumer grade SATA controller can understand communication in 4K sector.

512e IS a type of Advanced Format.

4Kn hard drive (4K native / 4096 logical) is for enterprise market only. You will not see them in consumer market anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot! Sector size is not a property of file system.

For a better understanding what a sector is, read:

- ["Understanding the Impact of Large Sector Media for IT Pros"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147334(v=ws.10).aspx). *TechNet*. Microsoft. 20 June 2012.